# Check for duplicate value among 10 combox boxes when summit excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, duplicates

I have 10 comboboxes on my userform that share 10 same selections, and I would like to check for duplicated value before summit.

As far as I can imagine, there are two ways to get the result, the first one is to check for same value among these ten boxes when summit by using message box OR to hide the selections from other comboboxes once the option is being selected by any one of the boxes.

Since I am new to vba, I am having a hard to grasp this idea in to code, please help.[Userform with 10 comboboxes that share the same selections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI4nf.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your second idea is the best, because it prevents the unwanted behavior instead of correcting it.

You can either build a responsive sql which filters out the already selected values, or you could create 10 queries, one for each combobox.

Start by creating a table with values you want to have for your selection.

Make a query like this: (Combobox1) `SELECT value FROM Table;`
This is the input query for your first combobox.

Create a second query (Combobox2) based on the first query. `SELECT value FROM Query1 WHERE value <> Forms!formname!Combobox1`
This will be the input query for your second combobox.

Now create a third query based on the second like: `SELECT value FROM Query2 WHERE value <> Forms!formname!Combobox2;` Which will be the input for your third combobox.

Keep on doing this untill you have a query for each combobox.

Comment: Thanks, I will start searching that direction.